# Решение проблемы с дублированием кода у различных сущностей с одинаковым порядком действий, но разной реализацией

Tags: c#, ооп, интерфейс

нужно разработать программу. Суть её заключается в следующем: нужно прочитать данные из документа, после провести правильность вводимых данных и записать эти данные в базу данных.

### Пример:

Имеется класс Car:

```
public class Car{
  public int Id {get;set;}
  public string Name {get;set;}
  public decimal Price {get;set;}
}
```

В документе записана следующая информация о автомобилях.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
1. Считываю построчно по машине из документа.
2. Проверяю, что названия автомобилей не повторяются и отрицательных цен нет в считанных машинах.
3. Записываю информацию о автомобилях в базу.
4. Архивирую исходный файл.
5. Загружаю на сторонний сервер сжатый файл.
```

Первый этап представлен следующим образом:

```
public class CarReader : ICarReader{
   public List<Car> ReadCarsFromExcel(Stream stream){
      //Создаю ExcelReader, после построчно считываю из документа поля автомобиля
   }
}
```

Второй этап представлен следующим образом:

```
public class CarValidator : ICarValidator{
   public List<ValidationError> ValidateCarsAsync(List<Car> cars){
      //Совершаю проверки и возвращаю для каждого поля успех/неуспех валидации с описанием в каком поел ошибка
   }
}
```

Третий этап представлен следующим образом:

```
public class CarDatabaseWriter : ICarDatabaseWriter{
   public async Task WriteCarsInDatabaseAsync(List<Car> cars){
      //Записываю информацию о машинах в базу
   }
}
```

4, 5 Этапы:

```
public class CarService: ICarService{
    public Task<List<ValidationError>> ImportCarsAsync(string pathToFile){
      var stream = File.OpenRead(pathToFile);
      try{
        var cars = _carReader.ReadCarsFromExcel(stream);
        var validationErrors = await _carValidator.ValidateCarsAsync(cars);
        if(validationErrors.Count==0)
            await _carDatabaseWriter.WriteCarsInDatabaseAsync(cars);
        return validationErrors;
      }catch(Exception ex){
         //обработка
      }finally{
        //Вызов метода архивации файла
        //Вызов метода загрузки файла на сервер
        //Удаление обоих файлов с локальной машины.
      }
    } 
}
```

Проблема заключается в следующем, если вводится допустим ещё одна сущность Колесо. Для неё будет реализован отличающийся от Автомобиля функционал чтения, валидации, записи в базу. Но архивация/загрузка/удаление файлов одинаковое, и придется в WheelService(Подобие CarService) дублировать эту логику, а если понадобится реализовать ещё один одинаковый функционал для файлов либо например убрать архивацию, то придется во всех Service`ах для каждого из сущностей производить правки, в которых можно ошибиться и мне кажется это ужасным решением.

### Мой вопрос заключается в следующем:

Каким организовать интерфейсы для данной программы, для решения этой проблемы? Буду очень признателен! И видать я не понимаю как решать подобные ситуации, когда имеются сущности со одинаковой логикой(схожая проблема имеется: есть программа для агрегации погоды, отправляющая запросы в разные сервисы с погодой, для каждого поставщика погоды приходится писать собственную реализацию для получения погоды, у каждого поставщика разный ответ, я изымаю нужную информацию из каждого поставщика и записываю информацию в базу, и выходит проблема такая же как и в основном моём вопросе, приходится дублировать Service`ы для каждого поставщика из чего вытекают те же проблемы).

Comment: Самый очевидный способ - создать базовый метод Process который переопеределять в наследниках. А вообще, тут есть два подхода. В первом Car не умеет обрабатывать сам себя, есть CarProcessor (Manager/Helper/etc) который работает над сущностью. Во втором подходе действительно логика внесена в сущности, но пардон, тогда ЭТО НЕ ОТВЕТСТВЕННОСТЬ КЛАССА ПО ЧТЕНИЮ/ЗАПИСИ СЕБЯ В ФАЙЛЫ. Персистенс - это отдельный слой и ваш домен не должен знать про своё сохранение в БД, про это знает DataAccessLayer. Названия полей В БАЗЕ не повторяются - это уже не ответственность авто, за это отвечает Repository.

Comment: А вот проверка "цена не нулевая"  - это действительно ответственность самого класса, а не репозитория. А вот подход с именами вызывает вопросы и первый из - это то, что у вас названия не приведены к первой нормальной форме (поле бренд отдельно, поле название отдельно) и ограничивать надо не название (в разных брендах могут совпасть), а в связке бренд + название. При строгом подходе ещё и продублировать в базе эти ограничения (уникальный индекс).